# jQuery has outdated data after vue changes

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I'm in the middle of migration between Jquery and Vue.js 3.

In this case, vue updated the DOM and Jquery still has outdated data.

Question: How can I force JQuery for having the new results just like vue and js (because `document.getElementById('modelSelect');` also return the updated data like vue)?

DOM after vue changes
[image: DOM after vue changes]

Object retrieved by JQuery (old data)
[image: Object retrieved by JQuery (old data)]

template

```
<select
    id="modelSelect"
    class="form-control"
    v-model="model"
>
    <option></option>
    <option
        v-for="(child, childIndex) in models"
        :key="childIndex"
        :value="child.id"
    >
        {{ child.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

vue changes

```
partAPI.getModels(newBrandId).then((result) => {
  models.value = result;

  nextTick(() => {
      let select = $("#modelSelect");
      select.chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true, width: "100%" });
  });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I have a similar implementation working just fine with the difference that the array used in v-for belongs to a ParentComponent instead of belonging to the same component as v-for.

Comment: You made a statement, but forgot to ask a question. Please ask a clear question, outline what is the expected result, what you have done to achieve the result, along with any link to docs stating what you tried should work.

Comment: This is one of countless reasons why using JQ with Vue is a bad thing. Generally it's expected that data is available on next tick but this shouldn't be relied on. v-for has its own rendering logic that obviously works like you see it. I'd highly recommend to rewrite it to proper Vue code.

Comment: If you're interested in why this happens, it's because Vue doesn't track the actual DOM for changes. It keeps a separate virtual DOM tree which is, well, virtual, therefore much faster. When data changes Vue updates DOM, based on virtual DOM. If you make mods to the real DOM via jQuery, Vue won't track those.

Comment: @EstusFlask I get your point and i would like to be working with Vue alone but with the migration in course i'll have to keep both for now.

Comment: If v-for is the problem here, wrap nextTick with setTimeout 0, i.e. wait and then a bit more. This is a hack that should be used as the last resort. If you believe it's the case then that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to solve this problem was actually very simple.

I just had to destroy the chosen element before initializing again.

```
$('#modelSelect').chosen("destroy");
partAPI.getModels(newBrandId).then((result) => {
  models.value = result;

  nextTick(() => {
    $("#modelSelect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true, width: "100%" });
  });
});
```

This issue can also be fixed by wrapping chosen element in a vue container.

The Jquery element still has outdated data but this way the chosen is created with the new data instead.